# Beamer: vertical bars in biblatex bibliography with ISO960 style

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I'm using `beamer` and the ISO960 style for `biblatex` (`style=iso-authoryear`). When printing the bibliography for a set of slides, each entry has a very thin vertical bar at the left edge of the frame that I would like to avoid. Here is an MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
%!TEX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{beamer-references-test.bib}
@Article{Hines2010,
  author    = {James R. Hines},
  journal   = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  title     = {Treasure {Islands}},
  year      = {2010},
  month     = nov,
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {103--126},
  volume    = {24},
  doi       = {10.1257/jep.24.4.103},
  publisher = {American Economic Association},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{beamer-references-test.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please don't mix different problems in a single post.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't.

Comment: How to change the font of the DOI is unrelated to the bibitem icon.

Comment: Which is why I didn't ask about that.

Comment: So why add the noise about it to your question?

Comment: Sam, I appreciate your answer to my question -- thanks again for that --, but I'm sure you'll understand that I have no further interest in this discussion here. If you feel the additional remark is out of place, you can edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a vertical bar, that's just the edge of the bibliography item icon which is pushed off the page.

For styles which are distributed as part of the biblatex package, beamer automatically fixes this, but you can use the same technique to fix your style as well:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>{%
  \pretocmd{\bibsetup}{%
    \settowidth\beamer@bibiconwidth{\usebeamertemplate*{bibliography item}}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\beamer@bibiconwidth}%
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{2\labelsep}%
    \addtolength{\bibhang}{\labelsep}%
  }{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{beamer-references-test.bib}
@Article{Hines2010,
  author    = {James R. Hines},
  journal   = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  title     = {Treasure {Islands}},
  year      = {2010},
  month     = nov,
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {103--126},
  volume    = {24},
  doi       = {10.1257/jep.24.4.103},
  publisher = {American Economic Association},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{beamer-references-test.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Is there, alternately, a way to remove this icon entirely?

Comment: @chsk `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}`